# how to remove header information in socket communication in java

Tags: java, sockets

I am new to Socket Programming.
I have connected to Server from my Client Program,But the response im getting is
Header info + Actual content(what i need ie XML data)
I just want to remove Headers.
This is my Code :

```
public class TestSocket{
public static void main(String args[]){
try{
URL url = new URL("http://xxxx.de:8080/abcd");

String path=url.getFile();
int port = url.getPort();
String host = url.getHost();


Socket cliSocket = new Socket(host,port);

String req = "yyyy";


        req="name="+req;
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(cliSocket.getOutputStream()));

             bw.write("POST " + path + " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
             bw.write("Host: " + host + "\r\n");
             bw.write("Content-Length: " + req.length() + "\r\n");
             bw.write("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");   
         bw.write("\r\n");
         bw.write(req);
                 bw.flush();




    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new      InputStreamReader(cliSocket.getInputStream()));
    String line;
System.out.println("Step 4 : Getting Input Stream");
StringBuffer serverData = new StringBuffer("");
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      serverData.append(line);      
}

System.out.println(serverData);    

String data = serverData.toString();
int index = data.indexOf("<");
String xmlData =null;
if(index!=-1){
 xmlData = data.substring(index);
System.out.println("XML Content :"+xmlData);        

}else{
System.out.println("XML Data Not Retrived");    
}



 bw.close();
 rd.close();

}catch(java.net.UnknownHostException uh){
System.out.println("UH : Host Not Found ");    
}catch(IOException ioe){
System.out.println("IO Exp "+ioe.getMessage());    
}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("Exp "+e.getMessage());    
}

}
}
```

Response :
    HTTP/1.1 200 OKServer: Apache-Coyote/1.1X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.3.GA    (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181417)/JBossWeb-2.0Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8Content-Length: 1110Date: Wed, 30 Apr 2014 12:13:10 GMTConnection: close

And then XML Data ,
 I just only need XML data , Not  HTTP/1.1 200 OKServer: Apache-Coyote/1.1X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.3.GA  .......... etc

Comment: can you please post the server data as well? I think you have to manipulate the data manually and remove the header information from the response in the code.

Comment: do you want to remove the xml header ? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678299/a-simple-way-to-remove-headers-from-xml-files

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133395/remove-xml-declaration-from-the-generated-xml-document-using-java

Comment: @Octopus Please look at response, i have edited the question

Comment: @latifmohammadkhan Kenneth's link takes you to the answer, accepted one.

Comment: @Octopus I have already written that code , in my  program, i need any other way ie . not by programming logic.I need any predefined techniq that seperates header and content

Comment: @latifmohammadkhan you can't expect it since you read the data directly from the inputstream, which will give you everything

Comment: @Octopus Is there any other way , in socket communication ?

Comment: @latifmohammadkhan AFAIK, there is no way.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) form Apache HttpComponents. This save you from most the HTTP stuff and lets you deal directly with the message content.